# ASP.NET Bootstrap table padding between columns not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css, asp.net-core

In the table in the following `View` of my ASP.NET MVC Core 1.1 app, I'm trying to create some space between columns `OrderNumber` and `ItemName`. But the content of the two columns are still too close to each other. Is it because `css` inside my `<style>....</style>` below is wrong or maybe the Bootstrap's default settings for the table are overriding my `css`. **Question**: How do I create the spacing between two columns?

```
@model MyProj.Models.TestViewModel
<style>
    table th td{
        padding-left:115px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.lstOrders)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="TestAction" asp-route-id="@item.OrderId">@item.OrderNumber</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.ItemName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

- define padding for the  elements in your CSS (recommended)
- insert an empty column in between the two, with a '&nsbp' value (a nasty hack, but proven effective)

... and your style definition is wrong (hint: there is no  element in your table).
Try simply

```
td {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS:

```
table th td {
    padding-left:115px;
}
```

means:

Give every `td` that is a child of `th` that is a child of `table` a left padding of 115px.

Instead, what you want to do is:

```
table th,
table td {
    padding-left:115px;
}
```

which means, give every `th` and `td` a left padding of 115px.